# Run PigUnit test on Windows env

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using Windows 7 as development env and Linux on production (so, my hadoop/pig is deployed only on linux). Now **I wish to use PigUnit for unit-testing on Windows**. 
Just for fun, I wrote simple word-count pig script and trying create unit-test for it. However, I faced in the following problem when run on my PC (Windows 7):

> 13/05/10 17:53:54 ERROR mapReduceLayer.Launcher: Backend error message
>   during job submission java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions
>   of path:
>   \tmp\hadoop-MyUsername\mapred\staging\MyUsername1049214732.staging
>   to 0700   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)

It seems PigUnit tries to create temporary folder on my local filesystem in Unix-way. So, in other words, does it mean I can't run Pigunit test on local filesystem? Or it is possible?
Thank you in advance

PS. **I expected that this unit test will be run in-memory, without using Pig itself. Please, correct me if I am wrong**
I don't have hadoop/pig on the machine where unit tests are running

Comment: are you using cygwin or the windows shell?

Comment: in fact, I just run unit test from my IDE (InteliJ Idea)

Comment: moreover, I don't have hadoop/pig on the machine where I'm going to run these unit tests.

Comment: ok guys, I solved it! The fix requires several steps, read here for details http://simpletoad.blogspot.com/2013/05/pigunit-issue-on-windows.html